# Python XML Element Replacement

Tags: python, xml, parsing, replace

How do I change the "year" value of country "Liechtenstein" in following XML in Python? I am referencing [Python's XML Element Tree](https://docs.python.org/2/library/xml.etree.elementtree.html#modifying-an-xml-file)

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<data>
    <country name="Liechtenstein">
        <rank updated="yes">2</rank>
        <year>2008</year>
    </country>
    <country name="Singapore">
        <rank updated="yes">5</rank>
        <year>2011</year>
    </country>
</data>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use **text** method like this:

```
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET

s = '''<?xml version="1.0"?>
<data>
    <country name="Liechtenstein">
        <rank updated="yes">2</rank>
        <year>2008</year>
    </country>
    <country name="Singapore">
        <rank updated="yes">5</rank>
        <year>2011</year>
    </country>
</data>'''

tree = ET.fromstring(s)

# I use iterfind, you can use whatever method to locate this node
for node in tree.iterfind('.//country[@name="Liechtenstein"]/year'):
    # this will alter the "year"'s text to '2015'        
    node.text = '2015' # Please note it has to be str '2015', not int like 2015

print ET.tostring(tree)
```

Results:

```
<data>
    <country name="Liechtenstein">
        <rank updated="yes">2</rank>
        <year>2015</year>
    </country>
    <country name="Singapore">
        <rank updated="yes">5</rank>
        <year>2011</year>
    </country>
</data>
```

If you want to change the node's attribute, use **set** like this:

```
for node in tree.iterfind('.//country[@name="Liechtenstein"]/year'):
    node.set('updated', 'yes') # key, value pair for updated="yes"
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: @Taewan, not a problem and I'm glad it helps. As a side note, you may want to check out [lxml](http://lxml.de/), it has more robust **xpath** supports and better performance :)

Comment: I have a very similar question related to this question. You mind look at it? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27773141/xml-arg-value-replacement-in-python

Comment: @Taewan, I've looked at it and posted an answer there :)